# how to escape single quote in xslt substring function

Tags: xslt, xpath

I tried to substring data with single quote in XSLT:

```
String : DataFromXML:'12345'
```

expected Result: `12345`

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after('$datafromxml','DataFromXML:')"/>
```

Result: `'12345'`

i tried below code

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after('$datafromxml','DataFromXML:&#39;')"/>

<xsl:value-of select="substring-after('$datafromxml','DataFromXML:&apos;')"/>

<xsl:value-of select="substring-after('$datafromxml','DataFromXML:'')"/>
```

Error:

```
String literal was not closed 'DataFromXML:'--->'<---
```

Comment: Did you try double quotes "''"?

Comment: Yes i tried it am getting compilation error

Comment: @prabhu, It *is* possible to extract the number with a single XPath 1.0 expression even in the most complicated case when the string contains both quotes and apostrophes -- not using any variable at all.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The general rules for escaping are:

In 1.0:

- if you want the attribute delimiter in a string literal, use the XML
  escape form `&quot;` or `&apos;`
- if you want the string delimiter in a string literal, you're hosed

In 2.0:

- if you want the attribute delimiter in a string literal, use the XML
  escape form `&quot;` or `&apos;`
- if you want the string delimiter in a string literal, double it (for
  example, 'I can''t')

The use of a variable $quot or $apos as shown by Vitaliy can make the code much clearer.

Comment: Michael, It is actually possible to extract the number with a single XPath 1.0 expression even in the most complicated case when the string contains both quotes and apostrophes -- not using any variable at all.

Comment: Possible, yes, but only by making such heavy use of entity references that the code becomes totally unreadable. And why are variables so bad anyway? - a good processor will inline them.

Comment: I don't have anything against using variables -- just addressed your statement that "if you want the string delimiter in a string literal, you're hosed" . Sorry for trying to be precise.

Answer (score 12):

This should work:

```
<xsl:variable name="apos">'</xsl:variable>

...

<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($datafromxml, concat('DataFromXML:', $apos)), $apos)" />
```

Comment: Not sure about XPath 1.0 rules - probably it could also be a simpler solution without special variable

Answer (score 8):

You could try swapping and " and ' in your **xsl:value-of**

```
<xsl:value-of select='substring-before
   (substring-after($datafromxml,"DataFromXML:&apos;"), "&apos;")'/>
```

Alternatively, you could make use of the translate function to remove the pesky apostrophes

```
 <xsl:value-of select='translate
    (substring-after($datafromxml,"DataFromXML:"), "&apos;", "")'/>
```

Not necessarily nicer, but it does remove the need for a variable.

Answer (score 4):

**Even in the most complicated case -- the string contains both a quote and an apostrophe -- the number can be extracted without resorting to variables**.

Suppose we have this XML document:

```
<t>' "12345' "</t>
```

and want to extruct just the number.

**In the following transformation we use a single XPath expression to do exactly that:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="text()">
     <xsl:value-of select=
     'substring-after(.,"&apos;")
     '/>
==============  
     <xsl:value-of select=
     'substring-before(
       substring-after(substring-after(.,"&apos;"), &apos;&quot;&apos;),
       "&apos;"
                       )
     '/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**The result is**:

```
 "12345' "
==============  
     12345
```

**Do note**: I am intentionally having two XPath expressions -- the purpose of the first one is to make it simpler to understand what is expressed in the second XPath expression. Leaving just the last `xsl:value-of` in the template body produces exactly the wanted result:

```
12345
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a note to my future self (or anyone else) who would benefit from a reminder of the *exact syntax that worked for me*.

Declare this variable

```
<xsl:variable name="apos" select='"&apos;"'/>
```

And use it in a condition like this

```
<xsl:if test="$value = concat('G-2', $apos, 'd')">89594</xsl:if>
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer, thanks Nick.

Comment: (I can't believe I ended up here a few weeks later looking for the same answer, and thinking, "I should mark this answer as correct", only to find out I already did : )