# XSLT check if string contains: '

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have to check that my XML don't contains sumbol ' in text fields. But I don't know how to order it, because such way it don't work:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="//Surname">
            <xsl:if test="contains(text(), ''')">
                <xsl:text>ERROR!</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

I tried `\'` and other variants, it don't works. How it is possible to do?

Comment: This question and answer might help you out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403870/how-to-escape-single-quote-in-xslt-substring-function

Comment: I tried &apos;, it doesn't work

Comment: Oh, yes, you were right. Solution with variable $apos works! Thank you very much.