# Selenium XPath with Single, double quotes and comma

Tags: selenium, xpath, vbscript

Trying to create `XPath` for below string (string is in .properties file and picked up by framework for further identification.):

```
If you would like to change your answers or finish a section that doesn’t have a checkmark, click on “Change”.
```

Tried below `XPath`:

```
CHANGE_ANSWER = xpath://ul/li[contains(.,concat('If you would like to change your answers or finish a section that doesn',"’", 't have a checkmark',",", ' click on ','“','Change','”','.'))]
```

Don't know what's exactly wrong.

Comment: Does it really need to be a full exact match? Seems like that text would be unique enough that it could be a partial match and still be unique on the page.

Comment: There are some more <LI> elements with Single quotes, Double quotes and Comma and have similar text. So if I can find XPath for above text I can  create same for rest of the texts, though complete match is not required.

Comment: Have you tried to escape it using \ before each char that you need to escape?

Comment: For string--

Once you’ve reviewed this summary and all the information is correct

--I tried:


A. REVIEW_SUMMARY = xpath://ul/li[contains(.,'Once you\\\'ve reviewed this summary and all the information is correct')]


B. REVIEW_SUMMARY = xpath://ul/li[contains(."Once you\'ve reviewed this summary and all the information is correct")]


C. REVIEW_SUMMARY = xpath://ul/li[contains(.'Once you&#8217;ve reviewed this summary and all the information is correct')]


Following works (w/o quotes):
REVIEW_SUMMARY = xpath://ul/li[contains(.,'Once')]      but i don't want this solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to escape single quote in xslt substring function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403870/how-to-escape-single-quote-in-xslt-substring-function)

Comment: Nopes...not related to that..