# How to use XPath to select text with a quote character?

Tags: c#, html, xml, xpath, webdriver

How can I select a xpath that contains a text with ""

Let say my text on the page is: "my text" (this includes the "").

When I make the xpath I do in VS:

```
"//td[contains(.,'"mytext">')]"
```

But VS doesnt see this as correct because it shows mytext in white as if it doesnt belong to the xpath

It says it is a syntax error and it expects an ','.

So how can I make an xpth that uses an contain where the text has an "".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple, escape the double quote characters:

```
"//td[contains(.,'\"mytext\">')]"
```

This is a reference of what characters need escaping: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2004/03/12/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available/

Hope it helps.

Comment: That reference page seems to be broken.

Answer (score 2):

If the context of your XPath is XML, then escape the double quotes with `&quot;`:

```
//td[contains(.,'&quot;mytext&quot;>')]
```

See also: [**Simplified XML Escaping**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46637835/290085)

If the context of your XPat is not XML, you might try

```
//td[contains(.,concat('"','mytext', '"', '>'))]
```

to see if VS is happier with that expression, or set a separate variable for `"` constant, and build up your XPath piecewise from it.

If that doesn't help in your context, see [***how to escape single quote in xslt substring function***](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12403870/290085)