# How to deal with single quotes in xpath in odoo 15?

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

I am trying to replace a `<t>` element using `xpath`, but it contains a single quote inside the condition.
here is what I tried.

```
      <xpath expr="//t[@t-if='receipt.client and env.pos.company.country and env.pos.company.country.code == 'IN'']" position="replace"/>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use XPath to select text with a quote character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50101617/how-to-use-xpath-to-select-text-with-a-quote-character)

Answer (score 3):

There are two solutions for this.

First :

```
<xpath expr="//t[@t-if=&quot;receipt.client and env.pos.company.country and env.pos.company.country.code == 'IN'&quot;]" position="replace"/>
```

Second :

```
<xpath expr="//t[contains(@t-if,&quot;receipt.client and env.pos.company.country and env.pos.company.country.code == 'IN'&quot;)]" position="replace"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using this form instead :

```
   <xpath expr="//t[@t-if][1]" position="replace"/>
```