# Using .Net XPath with source text containing '

Tags: .net, xpath

I have some XPath code that's working great 99% of the time. But now I have an XML document that contains unescaped characters in it. In this case the string I'm looking for is something like "Maury's bad string".

So how do I construct an XPath query to find this string? I tried escaping:

```
../a:Data[a:Name='" & NewT.Name.Replace("'", "&apos;") & "'"
```

But that fails to match the text. So then I tried:

```
../a:Data[a:Name='" & NewT.Name.Replace("'", "''") & "'"
```

But that tells me there's an invalid token in the search string.

Anyone know the trick here?

Comment: Maybe [how to escape single quote in xslt substring function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12406745/205233) helps.

Comment: It appears in my case "if you want the string delimiter in a string literal, you're hosed"

Answer (score 0):

This is NOT a complete solution, as it only works if the strings contain single or double quotes, but not both:

```
Dim S As String
If Name.Contains("'") Then
    S = ../a:Data[a:Name=""" & Name & """
Else
    S = ../a:Data[a:Name='" & Name & "'"
End If
```